# A local package.json file

Tags: node.js, package.json

Is it possible to have another package.json file load up that is only available locally and will override the options in the repo's package.json file. I have different version requirements for packages in my local machine for global things like yarn.

Comment: Would [`optionalDependencies`](http://npm.github.io/using-pkgs-docs/package-json/types/optionaldependencies.html) fit your use case?  Are you just trying to prevent accidentally committing your local `package.json` to version control?  Could you give a more concrete example of your need?  I don't understand needing varying versions just for yarn.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible and your best bet would be using the `devDependencies` field or using the `scripts` hooks to trigger specific `npm i` only locally

The approach with scripts would work similar to this

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "[\"$(hostname)\" == \"local-machine-hostname\" ] && npm i --no-save specific-package-local-only"
  }
}
```

(This triggers the `npm i` if the current machine's hostname is `local-machine-hostname`)

Bare in my however that this approach makes those commands public, if that is an issue.